# Any obvious reasons why this List does not scroll?

Tags: swiftui

I have this view with a List and a ScrollViewReader - and no matter what I try it does not scroll into position. I get a correct value in the print statement - but yet, nothing happens.

Anything obvious I am doing wrong?

```
struct ValueListView<T:CAPDataExchangable & Hashable>: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model:ValueListModel<T>
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List{
                ForEach(model.listValues,id:\.value){ value in
                    ValueListRowView(value: value, model:self.model)
                        .listRowBackground(value.isCurrent ? WatchStyle.listRowActiveBackgroundColor : WatchStyle.listRowBackgroundColor)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: model.currentValue, perform: { value in
                print ("CurrentValue now: \(value)")
                proxy.scrollTo(value, anchor: .center)
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all a matter of timing :-)

Both model.value and model.listValues are coming out of Publishers. At the time model.value was set model.listValues was still empty and no List in the view and no destination to scroll to.

.combineLatest(model.$listValues).map() on model.value did the job and now everything runs fine.